# Printing labels from an android app or Java?

Tags: java, android, printing

I've seen others discussing printing labels with a dedicated label printer using Java.

***Is there any way to print labels using a regular printer with label paper using (optimally) Android libraries/API? If not, is there any way to do this in a non-mobile context using Java?***

I'm not asking about preference; I'm asking about possibility. Is it possible to do this? I'd like to do it using android but feel that the range of printers that could be used would be increased if it were done with desktops/laptops. I simply need to know what's possible.

Searching for "Java Label Printing" is only turning up the aforementioned dedicated *label printer* approaches, which aren't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm concerned that this question doesn't fit StackOverflow as it doesn't seem low-level/implementation enough - I asked over at programmers because I felt that it was a design/whiteboard question (is it better to pursue obscure Android libraries with less compatibility, or force the user to export to desktop for a more compatible implementation?) Here's my programmers question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/242872/printing-labels-from-an-android-app-or-java

Gnat suggested that I post over here, so I've taken his advice given his experience with both sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may a bit broad for SO but it's close, IMHO. Anyway, sure you can print from Android devices if that's what you're asking. Obviously, printing from a desktop will give you more options and potentially better performance and output.

You will have to find printers with an Android SDK or, if using KitKat, you can create your own SDK using their recently added printing framework. I haven't had a chance to use that much yet but I have used the Brother label printer SDK for printing labels wirelessly from a tablet.

**Docs**

[Printing Content](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/)

[Printing custom documents](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html)

There is more in the docs but those should get you started if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Gotcha! It seems like I'd need to use libraries for different printers and would need to be able to use wireless connections to print if the user isn't using kitkat, and like that'd really hurt compatibility.

It seems that in that case, writing a Java application and exporting the file might be my best bet. Thank you for the prompt and helpful answer!

Comment: Yes, in your case it does sound as if a desktop app would be more suitable. You're welcome